# Mule 4 : Cloudhub deployment failed if properties are used

Tags: mule, cloudhub

When I add properties in cloudhub properties tab, the application is not getting deployed. No error/exceptions. Getting "update-failed" and the application is in yellow after trying for 15mins. Once I remove the properties, its getting deployed.

Any solutions for this?

Comment: What do the properties look like?

Comment: What does it say in the logs? Any error message?

Comment: Properties contain username/pswd/host/port information. I used this to quickly change and test endpoints without deploying the application everytime..

Comment: Logs does not contain any error message. Just says update failed